# prevent fragment refresh when back to fragment android xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have a program that retrieves information from a web service, and when I select a fragment and go back to the previous fragment, the information is reloaded. How can I keep the previous information and prevent it from reloading?

```
if (id == Resource.Id.navigation_carrots)
            {
                SupportFragmentManager
               .BeginTransaction()
               .Replace(Resource.Id.container, carrotsFragment, "carrots")
               .Commit();
            }
            else if (id == Resource.Id.navigation_dailylife)
            {
                SupportFragmentManager
               .BeginTransaction()
               .Replace(Resource.Id.container, dailyLifeFragment, "DailyLife")
               .Commit();
            }
```

How i can fix this problem?

tanks for help ♥

Answer (score 0):

You can see this lifecycle about Fragment in the below screenshot. `OnResume` method will be executed every time you load. You could always set the original status in this method to prevent refresh operation.

[image]